# c# A Queue of different Action

Tags: c#, queue, action

My Queue Class;

```
public class JobManager : MonoBehaviour {

private Queue<Action> queue;

public void AddAction(Action action)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(action);
    }
....
```

I have two methods:

```
void CreateCube()
{
   // doSomething..
}

void SetPosition(Vector3 pos)
{
   // doSomething..
}
```

I can use this:

```
JobManager.Instance.AddAction(CreateCube);
```

But this is not:

```
JobManager.Instance.AddAction(SetPosition);
```

How can i define a queue for all different Actions? Or How can i add different Actions?

Edit:

JobManager calling Actions like this;

```
    IEnumerator ActionControl(){
        while (true){
            if (currentQueue != null){
                while (true){
                    currentQueue();
                    yield return null;
                    currentQueue = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private void Update(){
        if (queue.Count > 0 && currentQueue == null){
            currentQueue = queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
```

What I really want is that any method can be placed in a single queue. (with parameter or not) Then we will run them in order. Is that possible?

Comment: Since calling `SetPosition` need an argument you have to pass it somehow. One way is to use lambda: `AddAction(() => SetPosition(pos))`

Comment: Suppose you could. How are you planning on calling `SetPosition` out of a queue of actions? It needs an argument; how are you going to pass the argument?

Comment: I edit my question and will try "AddAction(() => SetPosition(pos))" now..

Comment: Lambda is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is that `queue` is of type `Queue<Action>`. To accept this new type off action will likely need another queue of type `Queue<Action<Vector3>>`.

You'll need something like this:

```
public class JobManager
{
    private Queue<Action> plainQueue;
    private Queue<Action<Vector3>> vectorQueue;

    public void AddAction(Action action)
    {
        plainQueue.Enqueue(action);
    }

    public void AddAction(Action<Vector3> action)
    {
        vectorQueue.Enqueue(action);
    }
}
```

Also, `.AddAction(() => SetPosition(pos))` will work, but keep in mind that this is creating an anonymous `Action` that wraps the `Action<Vector3>`. It could lead to hard to debug code.

Comment: Lambda is working. It will not make error. isn't it? I never use before..

Comment: If you want it to work for all actions regardless of parameters then use the lambda to wrap it. `.AddAction(() => SetPosition(pos))` Just be mindfull that it's hiding the action with params inside an action without params.

Comment: I got it :) Thanks.